# Different noexcept property for std containers in different Compilers

Tags: c++, std, c++17

Is the move-constructors `noexcept` property for containers implementation defined? I just found out that the following will work in clang but not in gcc or msvc++:

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>> vector_a;
std::vector<std::stack<std::unique_ptr<int>>> vector_b;
vector_a.reserve(10);  // this works in all tested compilers
vector_b.reserve(10);  // this only works in clang
```

My question is, if this is caused by an incomplete implementation of the standard or if it is simply not defined (on purpose?).

I tested a few of the standard containers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <stack>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Deque: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::deque<float>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Vector: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::vector<float>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Queue: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::queue<float>>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Stack: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::stack<float>>::value << std::endl;
}
```

gcc 7.2.1:

```
Deque: 0
Vector: 1
Queue: 0
Stack: 0
```

clang 5.0.0:

```
Deque: 1
Vector: 1
Queue: 1
Stack: 1
```

Microsoft C/C++ Version 19.00.23506 for x64:

```
Deque: 0
Vector: 1
Queue: 0
Stack: 0
```

**EDIT**

Results for queue and stack using a vector as underlying container:

```
std::cout << "Vector Stack: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::stack<float, std::vector<float>>>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << "Vector Queue: " << std::is_nothrow_move_constructible<std::queue<float, std::vector<float>>>::value << std::endl;
```

gcc 7.2.1:

```
Vector Stack: 1
Vector Queue: 1
```

clang 5.0.0:

```
Vector Stack: 1
Vector Queue: 1
```

Microsoft C/C++ Version 19.00.23506 for x64:

```
Vector Stack: 1
Vector Queue: 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`stack` and `queue` are not containers; they are container *adapters*. They *use* a container type that you give them as a template argument. By default, they use `std::deque`.

<strike>As such, they forward the noexcept behavior of the container they're adapting. So if `deque` throws on move, so too will a `stack` that uses a `deque`.</strike> Actually, container adapters *don't* forward the noexcept behavior of their component containers. Or at least, they aren't required to by the standard.

As for the noexcept status of actual containers, `vector` is required to have a `noexcept` move (this was a C++17 change; there were no requirements previously). The rest are implementation-dependent.

Answer (score 2):

Only [`vector`](http://eel.is/c++draft/vector)'s move constructor is guaranteed `noexcept` and only starting from C++17.

[`deque`](http://eel.is/c++draft/deque), [`stack`](http://eel.is/c++draft/stack) and [`queue`](http://eel.is/c++draft/queue) move constructors aren't `noexcept`.
The fact that the LLVM's implementation is `noexcept` is a nice addition that does not contradict the standard.

You may want to look into the [`deque::swap()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque/swap), it offers similar functionality and is `noexcept` (also since C++17).